# Server Side Request Forgery (SSRF) vulnerabilities in Kentico

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, ssrf

Recently our workplace has been tightening down on security, and has brought in some rather robust scanning software to handle it, we have been able to get most of the vulnerabilities handled but one is eluding us, the SSRF or Server Side Request Forgery. It seems odd that there is so little that is put out on this item.

Anyway, I ask the community, is there something in Kentico that should be able to mitigate these attacks?  If so, how would it be implemented,  I am still fairly new to this side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Kentico support to prevent Cross site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF) - Refer this https://docs.xperience.io/securing-websites/developing-secure-websites/cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-xsrf